# How can i read the border info of the merger region from a excel template use POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a excel template with some merge regions, I want to read the border info of the merge regions,then i can extend the merge region from 1 to n, but now i do not know how to get the border info of the merge regions?

Comment: I use poi to operate the excel

Comment: The question is not clear. What is "the border info of the merge regions"? Merged regions are `CellRangeAddress`es which can be got from the sheet using `Sheet.getMergedRegions`. `CellRangeAddress` then provides methods to get first row and first column and last row and last column.